# Gitlab CI with Python flask app that use config.py?

Tags: python, flask, continuous-integration, gitlab

I use a config.py in my flask project to handle login to databases, store secret keys, and such.

example to the the config.py file:

```
import urllib.parse
import os

class Config:
    SECRET_KEY = '123'

    @staticmethod
    def init_app(app):
        pass


class DevelopmentConfig(Config):
    DEV = True
    # Configure Database URI:
    params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={ODBC};" +
                                     "SERVER=azure.com;" +
                                     "DATABASE=db;" +
                                     "UID=po;" +
                                     "PWD=12345")
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params
```

and I use it as such:

```
def create_app(config_name):
    app_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    template_path = os.path.join(app_path, 'server/templates/')
    static_path = os.path.join(app_path, 'server/static/')
    app = Flask(__name__, template_folder=template_path, static_folder=static_path)
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])
    config[config_name].init_app(app)

    db.init_app(app)
    mail.init_app(app)
    login_manager.init_app(app)

    app.register_blueprint(bp_front)
    app.register_blueprint(bp_back)
    app.register_blueprint(auth_blueprint, url_prefix='/auth')
    return app
```

Now everything works as expected, but I want to use Gitlab CI for testing, and since I have a test DB which I content to. So how do I get access to settings for connecting without committing the config.py to the repo?

How\Should I configure flask to use environment variables if the tests are executed by Gitlab CI?